# how to encrypt URL in android

Tags: android, encryption, share-intent

I am very new to this concept ,when i share my image and text to other app,my domain name was visible but i want to encrypt it and when user click that link it should be redirect to my play store app URL ,i google it but I am getting any solution for ,i saw this functionality in many app please help me how to d this here below one of the app show like this i need to encrypt and redirect to play store without opening that URL i need to redirect to play store please any one help me how to do that,here below one of the app using like this encryption and redirection with out showing their Main URL .
Here below the Image
[image]

Comment: Encryption? This is just URL shortening. Go to http://goo.gl/ to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think to make safe calls you need to encrypt it while sending and when user click on that image now you want to redirect to play store URL, so now decrypt it.

I found one library to do this job below is the link for example
https://github.com/simbiose/Encryption/blob/master/Examples/Android/app/src/main/java/se/simbio/encryption/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the image is not encrypted. It's an url Shortener. And in this case it's from google.  [Documentation about the Google URL Shortener](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/#get-app-deep-links-with-the-url-shortener)